# In the Common-validator latest version 1.7 the UrlValidator is giving the result as Invalid for some of the Urls which were valid in version 1.6

Tags: apache-commons

The following URL which I have specified is coming as InValid URL according to Commons-validator latest version 1.7

https://checkoutshopper-live.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/3dnotif.shtml?originKey=pub.v2.###MAASKED#####0012.aHR0cHM6Ly9jaGVja291dHNob3BwZXItbGl2ZS5hZHllbi5jb20.FRf3zC99VPpJ8Eg1gNYaiR_PxMLPZfWnHWc6uYhbyNw

where this URL was valid when I validated with version 1.6

Please help me out why this has happened? if the above URL specified is really invalid please specify the reason.

Answer (score 0):

In commons-validator version 1.6 url is validate against regex "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?". But in 1.7 url is validated with java.net.URL(String). Which is part of JRE. **In this "#" is not allowed in the URL.**